# javascript delete from array based on another array with same object and values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects (all the same object type). I have another array of the same object type in which I want to use to tell me which objects to delete from the first array. Is there an easy way to do this besides looping through all properties and comparing them to find the elements in the first array that 100% match the elements in the second array and then deleting from the first array?

I'm basically doing a jQuery.grep() on an array of objects and the resulting array from this grep I want to delete from the array I passed into it.

Comment: How are you checking for equality when comparing your objects?

Comment: Every property matches. What I'm deleting is always a subset of the first array, it's just that via jQuery.grep() to find the criteria of objects to delete, I get an array of those objects. Now I need to delete those objects from the first array I checked with grep().

Comment: Could the array listing the values to be deleted appear multiple times in the second array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using jQuery.grep(), to obtain a new array, replace it with [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/), returning the same object if it must be kept, or null if you want to remove it.

If for instance your code is

```
var toBeDeleted = $.grep(array, function(val) {
  return condition(val);
});
```

Change it to

```
array = $.map( array, function(val) {
  if(condition(val))
    return null;
  return val;
});
```

Comment: Good to know about this function. Not going to use it in this case, but this gave me an idea to extend jQuery with a delete() method where if the condition returns true then don't add to return array, if false add to return array. This works better with my database like library I'm making. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If all it is is an array of values that need to be deleted from another array then looping through the arrays is really quite easy.

```
function deleteMatchingValues( target, toBeDeleted, oneMatch ) {
    var i = target.length, j = toBeDeleted.length;

    while( i-- ) {
        while( j--) {
            if( target[i] === toBeDeleted[j] ) {
                target.splice(i,1);
                if( oneMatch ) { break; }
            }
        }
        j = toBeDeleted.length;
    }
}
```

The above function includes a parameter for when you know there is only single instances of the value in the array.

Comment: I don't like the dbl loop. I think I'm going to implement my own grep()/map() style and extend jQuery. Make a delete() in where if return true, then don't add to a new array and if false add that element to the new array and return the new array. That way I'm only looping through the 1 main array and should save myself many iterations.